# Monero hard fork - cant mine new transactions

Tags: mining, monero-forks

So i am trying to do a monero hard fork. I changed the ports, prefixes, etc.
I am running on a bit of an issue. I can't mine new blocks.

Here's the error:

```
 2019-04-27 22:07:02.425 [miner 0]       WARN    checkpoints     src/checkpoints/checkpoints.cpp:109     CHECKPOINT FAILED FOR HEIGHT 1. EXPECTED HASH: <771fbcd656ec1464d3a02ead5e18644030007a0fc664c0a964d30922821
a8148>, FETCHED HASH: <7989160f55d2b5deeb21f90fd4ae9c105642f2f354cd90c1cd84c4efff018d4a>
2019-04-27 22:07:02.425 [miner 0]       ERROR   blockchain      src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:3397 CHECKPOINT VALIDATION FAILED
2019-04-27 22:07:02.425 [miner 0]       ERROR   cn      src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1310    mined block failed verification
2019-04-27 22:07:02.497 [miner 0]       INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:495      Found block <2ad7c5252afc7d5c6630bcced4c76c911aaab7dc8f8dcc670e6afd8a6735e0bd> at height 1 for difficulty: 1
2019-04-27 22:07:02.497 [miner 0]       INFO    blockchain.db.lmdb      src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:591  [check_and_resize_for_batch] checking DB size
2019-04-27 22:07:02.497 [miner 0]       INFO    blockchain.db.lmdb      src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:559  DB map size:     1073741824
2019-04-27 22:07:02.497 [miner 0]       INFO    blockchain.db.lmdb      src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:560  Space used:      77824
2019-04-27 22:07:02.497 [miner 0]       INFO    blockchain.db.lmdb      src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:561  Space remaining: 1073664000
2019-04-27 22:07:02.497 [miner 0]       INFO    blockchain.db.lmdb      src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:562  Size threshold:  92160000
2019-04-27 22:07:02.498 [miner 0]       INFO    blockchain.db.lmdb      src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:564  Percent used: 0.0001  Percent threshold: 0.9000
2019-04-27 22:07:02.498 [miner 0]       INFO    verify  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:3367 No pre-validated hash at height 1, verifying fully
```

My `cryptonote_config.h`:

```
namespace config
{
  uint64_t const DEFAULT_FEE_ATOMIC_XMR_PER_KB = 500; // Just a placeholder!  Change me!
  uint8_t const FEE_CALCULATION_MAX_RETRIES = 10;
  uint64_t const DEFAULT_DUST_THRESHOLD = ((uint64_t)2000000000); // 2 * pow(10, 9)
  uint64_t const BASE_REWARD_CLAMP_THRESHOLD = ((uint64_t)100000000); // pow(10, 8)
  std::string const P2P_REMOTE_DEBUG_TRUSTED_PUB_KEY = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";

  uint64_t const CRYPTONOTE_PUBLIC_ADDRESS_BASE58_PREFIX = 60;
  uint64_t const CRYPTONOTE_PUBLIC_INTEGRATED_ADDRESS_BASE58_PREFIX = 61;
  uint64_t const CRYPTONOTE_PUBLIC_SUBADDRESS_BASE58_PREFIX = 62;
  uint16_t const P2P_DEFAULT_PORT = 17238;
  uint16_t const RPC_DEFAULT_PORT = 17239;
  uint16_t const ZMQ_RPC_DEFAULT_PORT = 17240;
  boost::uuids::uuid const NETWORK_ID = { {
      0x12 ,0x30, 0x71, 0xF1 , 0x61,  0x41, 0x04, 0x61, 0x31, 0x17, 0x00, 0x82, 0x16, 0xA1, 0x10, 0xA1
    } }; // Bender's nightmare
  std::string const GENESIS_TX = "013c01ff0001ffffffffffff0302BAxepF8U14PC2x98WiaKWuHdnj2dGEQHjYcsPMzRJohS8Yxt8cJtr8aG38A41k8M3ydKBRyc9fkkBHSoG5vW4hhLHGaaheP21017767aafcde9be00dcfd098715ebcf7f410daebc582fda69d24a28e9d0bc890d1";
  uint32_t const GENESIS_NONCE = 10000;
```

When i run status:
status

```
Height: 1/1 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 0 H/s, v1, up to date, 0(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 0m 2s
```

Any idea why can't i mine new blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
In file...: monero-${VERSION}/CMakeLists.txt

Change....: set(PER_BLOCK_CHECKPOINT 1)
To........: set(PER_BLOCK_CHECKPOINT 0)
```

Comment: Doesn't that compromise security?

Comment: Also it didn't work ://

Comment: What worked for is to open `build/release/Linus/release-${VERSION}/src/checkpoints.cpp` and comment out the checkpoints.
Example     `//ADD_CHECKPOINT(100,   "ac3e11ca545e57c49fca2b4e8c48c03c23be047c43e471e1394528b1f9f80b2d");`

Then do go to the `build/release/Linus/release-${VERSION}/` and run make and then just run the `monerod --offline` and it works.

Comment: If I remember correctly, when `set(PER_BLOCK_CHECKPOINT 0)`, and run monerod, the log output will tell you what hash being looked for.  Then change `ADD_CHECKPOINT(1,"LongHexString");` to `ADD_CHECKPOINT(0,"HashFromLogOutput");`  and comment out the rest of the `ADD_CHECKPOINT(n,"LongHexString");`.  This is from memory, so YMMV.